# ssh session not terminated upon exit

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, openssh

I am facing an issue whereby the ssh session is not terminated upon exit. Which will result in hitting the MaxSession defined in the `sshd_config` file.

```
ps auxwww | grep sshd:
root      7877  0.0  0.0  86884  3488 ?        Ss   10:42   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root      7989  0.0  0.0  86860  3832 ?        Ss   10:43   0:00 sshd: root@pts/1
root      8080  0.0  0.0  86860  3828 ?        Ss   10:43   0:00 sshd: root@pts/2
root     12364  0.0  0.0 109148   804 pts/2    S+   11:06   0:00 grep sshd:
```

The current configured ClientAliveInterval is as 0, meaning to say the server will not check with the client on the keep-alive status.

Is there a way or reason as to why my ssh session is not terminated clean ?

Comment: what were you doing in your ssh sessions? Can you take one of the process IDs, e.g. 7877 and paste the output of `pstree -p 7877` into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Not terminating connection does not change anything in case of `MaxSessions`. This option is used only for connection multiplexing (`ControlMaster` feature).

It very depends on how you exit your sessions. If you do that properly, the server side should exist straight away (unless there is something terribly broken. What OS are you using? What openssh version?). How long are these connections left open here?

Comment: Hi Jakuje, yes i agree with you. I have tested in my lab environment, various method of exiting/terminating an ssh session.

I am suspecting that the sshd service might have hung which is why i am receiving that error.